# java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "svt-srv-41": No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, json, api

I got error of unknown host exception.

My code for api is:

```
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                //httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordCredentials("test-user@example.com", "Password!"), "UTF-8", false));

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }
```

**I have also given internet permission in Manisest file,**

Is there any problem with logic for web service calling or there is any issue from the web site side, i don't know what is wrong i am doing please help me.

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Method looks correct , Check the URL you are passing to the method.

Comment: I can get data in browser from passing the URL, but in application i get this exception.